# Android - DatagramSocket with source port 800 not sending

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a little tool which sends UDP packets from port 800 (Android) to a PC (Windows) on port 804 , so im using DatagramSocket(800) , it just doesnt work while (almost) all other ports work (usually 4 digits ports) so i was wondering if 800 is reserved on Android (i tried netstat and couldnt find something using port 800) and if there is any work around it (except Rooting).
I cant really change the ports because they are fixed , so its either 800->804 or nothing will work!

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'. I would expect a bind exception. Not 'not sending' as in your title.

Comment: @EJP yes by not working i meant the Packet isnt being sent at all

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you have to hold root privileges to be able to bind to port lower than 1024. Unless you are able to make your app privileges elevated and act as root (at least for while binding, you can later drop back to regular user as most software utilizing "lower" ports do), you must choose other port to succeed. That's why your "4 digits port number" tests works (yet i.e. 1000 would fail :), while 800 not.

Comment: i see , and since rooting is not an option in my case than i guess i just hit a dead end , thank for your answer @Marcin